# Best way to handle negative sampling in Tensorflow 2.0 with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Tensorflow released an official guide to implementing word2vec in TF 2.0 Keras

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings

However, it's missing negative sampling, which is very important in word2vec, which is unfortunate, because the original tensorflow has some great candidate sampling functions.

My best guess on what to do is augment the model,

```
model = keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(encoder.vocab_size, embedding_dim),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

Perhaps use the functional API instead of the sequential API.

I see that the c++ TF 2.0 has candidate sampling ops https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/group/candidate-sampling-ops

Can these be incorporated into Keras?

Answer (score 3):

**`Negative Sampling`** is a technique in which the Values which are not in the `Context` it simply Samples a Small Number of them instead of Reducing the Values of their `Weights`.

So, in our Implementation, we use an Activation of "Sigmoid" instead of "Softmax". So, for the words which are in `Context`, we want our `Network` to `Output` `1` and `0` for the words which are not in the `Context`.

Yes, your observation is correct that we need to use `Functional API` instead of `Sequential API`.

Code to implement **`Negative Sampling`** in `Keras` is shown below:

```
# create some input variables
input_target = Input((1,))
input_context = Input((1,))

embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, vector_dim, input_length=1, name='embedding')

target = embedding(input_target)
target = Reshape((vector_dim, 1))(target)
context = embedding(input_context)
context = Reshape((vector_dim, 1))(context)

# setup a cosine similarity operation which will be output in a secondary model
similarity = merge([target, context], mode='cos', dot_axes=0)

# now perform the dot product operation to get a similarity measure
dot_product = merge([target, context], mode='dot', dot_axes=1)
dot_product = Reshape((1,))(dot_product)
# add the sigmoid output layer
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dot_product)

# create the primary training model
model = Model(input=[input_target, input_context], output=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

# create a secondary validation model to run our similarity checks during training
validation_model = Model(input=[input_target, input_context], output=similarity)
```

For more information, please refer this [Awesome Article](https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/).

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!